# Update table values to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-update

What I have is a html based website and with rows out of the database.

**What I want:** 
I want it to update the fields with 1 button, The problem I have right now that it will not update the right row. It will update the first in the database.

I want it to update only the things that have been eddited ( for example 1 or 2 out of the 10) and the rest to stay the same.

[How my page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx7B9.jpg)

[How the database is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9jyn.jpg)

```
$PAGES = $app->get_pages();
  foreach($PAGES as $Pages){
    echo "
      <tr>
      <td>".$Pages['id']."</td>
       <form action='' method='post'>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control profiel' name='PageName' value='".$Pages['naam']."'</td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control profiel' name='PageUrl' value='".$Pages['url']."'</td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control profiel' name='PageStatus' value='".$Pages['status']."'</td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control profiel' name='PagePos' value='".$Pages['positie']."'</td>

       <input type='hidden' name='pageID' value='".$Pages['id']."'>
       <td><button type='submit' name='deletePage'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        ";
       }
      echo "
        </tbody></table>
         <button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' name='updatePage'>Bewerk</button>
         </form>



if(isset($_POST['updatePage'])){
                unset($updateVAL);
                $updateVAL['naam'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PageName']);
                $updateVAL['url'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PageUrl']);
                $updateVAL['status'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PageStatus']);
                $updateVAL['positie'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PagePos']);
                $app->update_tabel('pages', $updateVAL);
                }
```

Function for the update:

```
public function update_tabel($tabel, $updateVAL){
        $q = '';
        foreach ($updateVAL as $key => $value) {
            $value  = str_replace("'","&#39;",$value);
            $q .= "`".$key."` = '".$value."',";
        }

        if(isset($q) && ($q !='')) {
            $q = substr($q,0,-1);
            $this->database->query("UPDATE ".$tabel." SET ".$q." LIMIT 1");
            $this->database->execute();
        }   
    }
```

**Example**

for example if I eddit 'Support' and make 'Supporttt' of it it will edit it in the database **BUT** it will set 'Home' to 'Suporttt' and it will not change 'Support' to 'Suporttt' so It updates not the right records

Comment: there is no where condition and since you have set the limit to 1, it updates the first row

Comment: @coder What for `where` condition do I have to give it?

Comment: where id = some number eg . if you want to updae the first row, WHERE id = 1

Comment: what you posted contains parse errors. Look at syntax highlighting.

Comment: @coder that is hard coded, I need it to be different every time depending on which row you customize. in fact it has to update the entire database

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well this is made in a PDO and the function works but it is not working correctly

Comment: @murkmurrell maybe my answer will help

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like:

```
$this->database->query("UPDATE ".$tabel." SET ".$q." WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do. You see you set a hidden field called pageID.Use that hidden field as the where clause condition for the update query.

change the code as follows

```
    if(isset($_POST['updatePage'])){
            unset($updateVAL);
            $updateVAL['naam'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PageName']);
            $updateVAL['url'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PageUrl']);
            $updateVAL['status'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PageStatus']);
            $updateVAL['positie'] = $app->check_string($_POST['PagePos']);
$id = $app->check_string($_POST['pageID']);

            $app->update_tabel('pages', $updateVAL,$id);
            }
```

Change the update function as follows

```
    public function update_tabel($tabel, $updateVAL,$id){
    $q = '';
    foreach ($updateVAL as $key => $value) {
        $value  = str_replace("'","&#39;",$value);
        $q .= "`".$key."` = '".$value."',";
    }
rtrim($q,',');
$q .= " WHERE id = $id";

    if(isset($q) && ($q !='')) {
        $q = substr($q,0,-1);
        $this->database->query("UPDATE ".$tabel." SET ".$q." LIMIT 1");
        $this->database->execute();
    }   
}
```